# How to map custom collection in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, jpa, persistence

I have problems in mapping custom collection with JPA (Hiberante provider). For example when I am using object with attribute

```
List<Match> matches;
```

with

```
<one-to-many name="matches">
    <cascade>
        <cascade-all />
    </cascade>
</one-to-many>
```

in my ORM file, it is allright; But if I replace *"List matches;"* by

```
private Matches matches;
```

,where *"Matches"* is defined like:

```
public class Matches extends ArrayList<Match> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

It produces following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: by.sokol.labs.jpa.MatchBox.matches
```

Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can, but you have to refer to it as one of the common collections - `List` or `Set`.

so:

```
private List matches = new Matches();
```

Why? Because Hibernate makes proxies to your collections to enable lazy loading, for example. So it creates `PersistentList`, `PersistentSet` and `PersistentBag`, which are `List` but aren't `Matches`. So, if you want to add additional methods to that collection - well, you can't.

[Check this article](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=54694) for more details.

You have a solution, however. Don't use inheritance, use composition. You can, for example, add a method to your entity called `getMatchesCollection()` (in addition to the traditional getter), which looks like:

```
 public Matches getMatchesCollection() {
    return new Matches(matches);
 }
```

And your `Matches` class would look like (using [google-collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/)' `ForwardingList`):

```
public class Matches extends ForwardingList {
    private List<Match> matches;
    public Matches(List<Match> matches) { this.matches = matches; }
    public List<Match> delegate() { return matches; }
    // define your additional methods
}
```

If you can't use google collections, simply define the `ForwardingList` yourself - it's calling all the methods of the underlying `List`

If you don't need any additional methods to operate on the structure, then don't define a custom collection.

Answer (score 5):

Hibernate requires persistent collection-valued fields to be declared as an interface type (because they will be replaced with Hibernate's  implementation for lazy loading purposes). From the reference documentation:

> #### [6.1. Persistent collections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html)
>
> Hibernate requires that persistent collection-valued fields be declared as an interface type. For example:
>
> ```
> public class Product {
>     private String serialNumber;
>     private Set parts = new HashSet();
>
>     public Set getParts() { return parts; }
>     void setParts(Set parts) { this.parts = parts; }
>     public String getSerialNumber() { return serialNumber; }
>     void setSerialNumber(String sn) { serialNumber = sn; }
> }
> ```
>
> The actual interface might be
>   `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Collection`,
>   `java.util.List`, `java.util.Map`,
>   `java.util.SortedSet`,
>   `java.util.SortedMap` or anything you
>   like ("anything you like" means you
>   will have to write an implementation
>   of
>   `org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType`.)
>
> Notice how the instance variable was
>   initialized with an instance of
>   `HashSet`. This is the best way to
>   initialize collection valued
>   properties of newly instantiated
>   (non-persistent) instances. When you
>   make the instance persistent, by
>   calling `persist()` for example,
>   Hibernate will actually replace the
>   `HashSet` with an instance of
>   Hibernate's own implementation of `Set`.

So your second approach is not possible, at least not the way you declared it. But to be honest, I don't really see the point.