# How to persist a custom map with Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to persist a sub-classed `HashMap` in a database using Hibernate and JPA annotations.

```
import javax.persistence.CollectionTable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MapKeyColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "module")
public class Module {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "version")
    private String version;

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "module_parameter")
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "key")
    @Column(name = "value")
    private Parameters params = new Parameters();

    // Getters & setters

}
```

This gives me the following exception when trying to store parameters:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: Module.params
```

When I change the declaration to

```
private Map<String, String> params = new Parameters();

public Parameters getParams() {
    return (Parameters) params;
}
```

I get the following output:

```
Hibernate: select module0_.id as id1_0_, module0_.description as descript2_0_, module0_.name as name3_0_, module0_.version as version4_0_ from module module0_
Hibernate: select params0_.Module_id as Module_i1_0_0_, params0_.value as value2_1_0_, params0_.key as key3_0_ from module_parameter params0_ where params0_.Module_id=?
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentMap cannot be cast to Parameters
```

If I change it to

```
private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
```

everything works fine.

So how can I tell Hibernate about `Parameters` being a collection?

Comment: FWIW what you have above would work out of the box with the JPA implementation I use (DataNucleus). Maybe some JPA impls only provide support for explicit types like Map, HashMap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is untested*. Perhaps you can try and see if this works: Why not just return a `Map<String, String>`?

JPA works using common collection interfaces: `List`, `Set`, `Map`. Thus, if `Parameters` *IS-A* `Map`, you can return it as a `Map`.

Change:

```
public Parameters getParams() {
    return (Parameters) params;
}
```

To:

```
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
```

Also, because Hibernate has classes that allows lazy loading, i.e., `PersistentList`, `PersistentSet`, `PersistentMap`, etc., you can use composition to return a `Parameters` of what is returned by Hibernate.

So, you can essentially customize your method to return the values from the returned Hibernate collection.

Something of this effect:

```
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return new Parameters(params); //params is injected with Hibernate's PersistentMap.
}
```

Comment: Because I need the `Parameters` class elsewhere.

Comment: If your `Parameters` class is a subclass of `Map`, you can return it as a `Map`.

Comment: It is a sub-class of `HashMap` (and thus implements `Map`). I know that I can return it as a `Map`, but I don't want a `Map`.

Comment: Read my reply. Hibernate uses Reflection to map a type to its general collection types. `Parameters` is not registered with Hibernate, yet alone JPA, so you will have to use `Map`. Later, in your code, you can use `instanceof` to check if the `Map` is a `Parameters`.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't want to check repeatedly if I got `Parameters` or another `Map`. Using your last method, the changes made to the map would not be made to the models map but to a new one. Thus I would also always have to set the map again, after applying changes to it.

Comment: Well, you have no choice since you cannot add/update anything value in a Hibernate `PersistentMap` when injected since they're immutable. That's the option you have.

Comment: I have chosen the composition approach now. `Parameters` implements `Map` and I forward all calls to the methods defined in `Map` to the internal Map. Somehow the internal map is not immutable and I can still put new entries directly into the map returned by the getter.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a class that implements [UserCollectionType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserCollectionType.html) interface and then provide this class to hibernate to tell that you want to use the custom collection.

See these links to understand how you can create custom collections:

[How to map custom collection in JPA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174379/how-to-map-custom-collection-in-jpa)

[Hibernate: Custom Collection Types](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91832311.html)

Comment: This sounds interesting, but it defines some methods that are not applicable for maps, because they don't implement `Collection`. How do I have to implement them?

Comment: The examples you've given `UserCollectionType` is only valid for Hibernate. If one have to use JPA specific API, this would not work (e.g. with TopLink JPA).