# JPA - load Set as immutable

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2.1 in my project and want to all of my loaded Sets  to be immutable.

I read this: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174379/how-to-map-custom-collection-in-jpa) and I am confused.

Is my goal possible to achieve with JPA 2?

Comment: Use `return Collections.unmodifiableSet(mySet);`?

Comment: I don't want to do this at getter level and modyfi each entity.